# How can I acces a nested object from my API

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, object, nested

I made an API with spring-boot that is able to create Cook objects with Recipes objects in it. The idea is that one cook has a relationship with (multiple) recipe(s). When I perform a get request to my server, I am able to show the entire (Cook) object with nested (Recipe) object(s). I am also able to render Cook object properties to the browser, e.g name, age etc. However, I am not able to render Recipe properties to the browser from within the Cook object. It always gives me an undefined.

My code for the API request that shows the name from a cook correctly :

```
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=> {
        axios.get(" http://localhost:9090/api/cooks")
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)  //response.data.recipe.x doesn't seem to work.
                setPosts(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.name}</li>)}; //post.recipe.x also doesn't work
        </div>
    )
}

const Index = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Alt />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The raw JSON data from the server looks like this:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bart",
    "surName": "Janssen",
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 3,
    "recipes": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "recipeName": "Hamburger",
        "portion": 1,
        "meat": "Ground meat",
        "vegetable": "Tomato, Pickles, other greens",
        "other": "salt, pepper, mustard, ketchup",
        "instructions": "bla bla"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "recipeName": "tomato soup",
        "portion": 2,
        "meat": null,
        "vegetable": "tomato",
        "other": "salt, stock",
        "instructions": "bla bla"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

However, I really need to access the Recipe properties too.
I tried accessing recipes through `response.data[0]`, `response.data[0][0]`, `response.data[0][1]`, `response.data[[0][0]]` However, they all seem to give me an undefined back or an error.

I also tried to use `JSON.Stringify(response.data)`, but this didn't give me any successes too.

I really could use some help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use *useEffect* with async/await

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      'http://localhost:9090/api/cooks',
    );

    setData(result.data.recipes);
  });
```

and another moment, you initialize

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
```

as an array - useState(**[ ]**), but trying to write a **data** as **object** -

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "bart",
    "surName": "Janssen",
....
}
```

that's why you need to straight extract recipes

```
setData(result.data.recipes);
```